# OxyPlot WPF- Find Y value from X-Axis value

Tags: wpf, linechart, oxyplot

I am trying to find Y-Axis value from X-Axis but so far no luck .  My graph is plotted with 10-15 points with smooth curve set to true. Now what I need to locate is probable value of Y for any given x-value. Slimier to what occurs on click of graph (i think its nearest value displayed on tracker). Please note that I cant use tracker and click events. X-axis value will be provided from external input.

sample image 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMwJo.png

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Are you doing this in code-behind? Are you using MVVM?  How do you have access to the control, but not to the data that you feed the control?

Comment: I am using MVVM and plotting using PlotView & PlotModel.